# Unable to update ToolStrip using class file

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls, toolstrip

Here is a simple example of what I am doing in the real application

FORM CONTAINING MAIN SUB OpenNew.vb

Step 1 - Main prompts user for input using dialog in same file (OpenNew.vb)
Step 2 - Users Selects What type of Project they are opening, Type 1 or Type 2
Step 3 - strOpenNewResponse is populated when OpenNew dialog is closed
Step 3 - Form is opened based on selection

```
Public Class OpenNew

    Public Shared strOpenNewResponse As String = Nothing

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        OpenNew.ShowDialog()

    If strOpenNewResponse IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim formToShow As Form = Nothing

        Select Case strOpenNewResponse
            Case "Type1"
                formToShow = New Form1
                formToShow.ShowDialog()
            Case "Type2"
                formToShow = New Form2
                formToShow.ShowDialog()
        End Select

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Form1 would have a StatusBar with one ToolStrip and a TreeView:

```
Public Class Form1

Inherits Form

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

    Utilities.DisplayStatus("Loading, Please Wait...")

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    PopulateTreeView("Root Node")

    Utilities.DisplayStatus("Process Complete")

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

End Sub

End Class
```

Then the Class file is named Utilities.vb

```
Public Class Utilities

Public Shared Sub DisplayStatus(ByVal strStatusMessage As String)

    Form1.toolstripDisplayStatus.Text = strStatusMessage
    Form1.toolstripDisplayStatus.Visible = True
    Form1.statusstripParent.Refresh()

End Sub

End Class
```

When I do this the ToolStrip Item never updates.  It just stays the default value.

Of Course if I run it this way (without the class)

```
Public Class Form1

Inherits Form

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    toolstripDisplayStatus.Text = "Loading, Please Wait..."
    toolstripDisplayStatus.Visible = True
    statusstripParent.Refresh()

    PopulateTreeView("Root Node")

    toolstripDisplayStatus.Text = "Process Complete"
    toolstripDisplayStatus.Visible = True
    statusstripParent.Refresh()

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

End Sub

End Class
```

I thought it might be a problem with some sort of Public/Private conflict but I still can't seem to figure it out.

I might just be blinded by the obvious at this point

Can anyone give me an idea what might be causing this?

ADDED A SCREENSHOT for soohoonigan

[image]

Comment: When you're using the utilities class, I don't see a reference to the main form getting passed to it anywhere. Your compiler doesn't highlight the text "Form1" inside that class?

Comment: Nope, just pointing to Form1 like always

Comment: How are you opening your form? Are you opening it yourself or is it opened as the first form of your application?

Comment: In the actual application it gets opened using ShowDialog()

Comment: Works for me using 2013 Community. Instead of `PopulateTreeView` I pulled some data from a database table.

Comment: I think I didn't word this right.  The basic example does work.  The real application does not.  let me add something that looks more like the real app.

Comment: I added the "Sub Main" part to it as well, sorry about that

Comment: I can't tell you why, but `formToShow = Form1` will work (remove the `New`)

Comment: That's it!  THANKS a billion!  I thought I needed to create a new object because the "InitializeComponent()" is in Sub New of Form1.  but everything works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formToShow = Form1` will work (remove the New)

Your Utilities class  is referencing Form1 directly, but you have just an instance of that. Alternatively, if you need multiple instances of Form1 you could pass in the form to the Sub like this:

```
Public Shared Sub DisplayStatus(ByVal temp As Form1, ByVal strStatusMessage As String)

    temp.toolstripDisplayStatus.Text = strStatusMessage
    temp.toolstripDisplayStatus.Visible = True
    temp.statusstripparent.Refresh()

End Sub
```

and call it like such:

```
Utilities.DisplayStatus(Me, "Loading, Please Wait...")
```

Comment: Thanks again, that will be very useful

Comment: @mreinsmith You're welcome. Do you understand now why it didn't work as you had it coded?

Comment: I believe so,  in creating a NEW object formToShow,  i would have had to be referencing that instead of form1

Comment: Partially, except that formToShow would be out of scope in the class, hence why the actual instance of the form1 object that was created by formToShow needs to pass itself to Utilities.